# Trouble using HTTP POST with libsoup

Tags: rss, vala

I am trying to log on to my tt-rss server using libsoup. Since version 1.5.3 it only supports HTTP POST to receive data.
Basically I only need to do something like this with libsoup:

```
curl -d '{"op":"login","user":"you","password":"xxx"}' http://example.dom/tt-rss/api/
```

But all the code examples written in vala using POST are outdated and don't compile anymore.
For example the last one on this page, Transmission RPC Interface:
https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/JsonSample

Here is my code:

```
var uri = "http://nas/tt-rss/api/";
var session = new Soup.Session ();
var message = new Soup.Message ("POST", uri);
var login = "{\"op\":\"login\",\"user\":\"USER\",\"password\":\"PASSWORD\"}";
message.set_request("", MemoryUse.COPY, login);
session.send_message (message); 
stdout.printf("%s \n", (string) message.response_body.flatten ().data);
```

I always get the error:

```
Argument 3: Cannot convert from `string' to `uint8[]'
```

Thanks for any help in advance

best regards,
Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Soup.Message.set_request](http://valadoc.org/#!api=libsoup-2.4/Soup.Message.set_request) takes a byte array, `uint8[]`, not a `string`, as you have provided. You can convert a `string` to an array of bytes using the `.data` member:

```
message.set_request("", MemoryUse.COPY, login.data);
```