# Vala HTTPS Post request to script

Tags: http, post, vala

I need to send an HTTPS Post request to the address, for example: `mysite.com/auth.php`, using this GIO lybrary. 
Please help my.

Comment: GIO alone is not enough, you need something that actually understands HTTP. Take a look at libsoup, you can probably adapt the example here: https://valadoc.org/libsoup-2.4/Soup.Message.html

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25405045/trouble-using-http-post-with-libsoup